# Copy and Write XML Node in Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

I've got a large XML file that I need to parse and look for a specific node. Once it has been found, I need to make a copy, edit a couple of values and write the file again.

So far I've managed to get the DOM element that I want. There is actually two of these elements already in the XML so after I'm finished, there will be three. Once I've made a copy of the DOM and edited the value, how do I then write this into the DOM (and thus the file)?

I'm using Python's `from xml.dom import minidom` at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In minidom you start with creating Document:

```
 Document doc = Document("your_root")
```

then if it is a text node you want to add, you append it with:

```
 text_node = doc.createTextNode(str(some content))
 doc.appendChild(text_node)
```

if you had for example `<some_elem key="my value">some my text</some_elem>`:

do it like this:

```
text_node = doc.createTextNode('some my text')
elem.appendChild(text_node)
elem.setAttribute('key', 'my value')
```

if it is complex element create it with:

```
elem = doc.createElement('your_elem')
```

if you need to set attributes do:

```
elem.setAttribute("some-attribute",your_attr)
```

if you need to append something to it:

```
elem.appendChild( some_other_elem )
```

then append the element:

```
doc.appendChild( elem )
```

if you need a string representation do:

```
doc.toxml()
```

of

```
doc.toprettyxml()
```

Comment: If I have an element of the form `<FIELD ID="abc" TITLE="hello">VALUE</FIELD>`. How do I set the VALUE once I have the element? Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: Try doing a: `field.childNodes[0].nodeValue = new_val`. Catching any IndexErrors and the like.

Answer (score 1):

From the [minidom documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import getDOMImplementation

impl = getDOMImplementation()

newdoc = impl.createDocument(None, "some_tag", None)
top_element = newdoc.documentElement
text = newdoc.createTextNode('Some textual content.')
top_element.appendChild(text)
```

So I guess `appendChild` is what you ask for?